# Adding a prefix parameter to an array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to add a prefix to an array, and they are both parameters in a function. the array has 10 items and I need, in each item, to add the prefix to the item of the array. Then, I need to return the new array where I merged the prefix with the element of the array. I tried this:

```
   function series(prefix, arr)
    { 
     var finalArr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{ finalArr = prefix + arr[i]} 
return finalArr
}
```

and also this:

```
 function series(prefix, arr)
{ 

 var finalArr = []
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{ finalArr.push(prefix + arr[i])}
 return finalArr
}
```

None of them worked. finalArr should be something like:

```
var finalArr = ['prefix array(0)', 'prefix array(1)', 'prefix array(2)', until 10...]
```

I would appreciate if the solution used loop for and return! Ty in advance!

**EDIT:
Ok so I got the solution, and it is basically the second one with a ' '. Here it is:**

```
function series(prefix, arr)
    { 
    
     var finalArr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    { finalArr.push(prefix + ' ' + arr[i])}
     return finalArr
    }
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: The first attempt doesn’t work because you override the array. The second should work just fine though... except there might not be a space between the prefix and the value.

Comment: Indeed the second worked. I forgot to space the elements in the array, so it was not working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to do this.

```
const prefixedArray = originalArray.map(element => {
    return "some prefix" + element;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does work, however, I planned to use loops and .push to get better in my skills. I'm a begginer... Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
const series = (prefix, arr) => arr.map(item => `${prefix} ${item}`)
```

Comment: Yes it does work, however, I planned to use loops and .push to get better in my skills. I'm a begginer... Anyway, thank you!